# nested ng-repeats in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to work with some nested repeats here with angular.js and can't seem to get it to work. I have structured my json like so -

```
[
 {
"levels": [
  {
    "targets": [
      "one", 
      "two", 
      "three", 
      "four"
    ], 
    "response": "response", 
    "instructions": "insturctions"
  }
  ], 
"name": "Name One", 
"form": [
  {
    "pfade": "fade", 
    "ptype": " type", 
    "psection": "section", 
    "lbehavior": "l behave", 
    "options": "options", 
    "tbehaviour": "t behave"
  }
]
}, 
{
"levels": [
  {
    "targets": [
      "one", 
      "two", 
      "three", 
      "four"
    ], 
    "response": "response", 
    "instructions": "insturctions"
  }
], 
"name": "Name Two", 
"form": [
  {
    "pfade": "fade", 
    "ptype": " type", 
    "psection": "section", 
    "lbehavior": "l behave", 
    "options": "options", 
    "tbehaviour": "t behave"
  }
]
}, 
{
"levels": [
  {
    "targets": [
      "one", 
      "two", 
      "three", 
      "four"
    ], 
    "response": "response", 
    "instructions": "insturctions"
  }
], 
"name": "Name Three", 
"form": [
  {
    "pfade": "fade", 
    "ptype": " type", 
    "psection": "section", 
    "lbehavior": "l behave", 
    "options": "options", 
    "tbehaviour": "t behave"
  }
]
}
]
```

also link here if you prefer : http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOyGmHavfS?indent=2

I am trying to loop through the sub arrays in a repeat, and I can't seem to (refer?) to them correctly. I found some other examples of ng-repeats nested and they seemed to have no problem doing it like this, so here it my stab at it

```
<!--  parent level repeats -->
                        <tr class="saLevel" ng-repeat="parent in listTable track by $index">

                            <td></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="instructionLevelChecker" ng-model="levelRadio" ></td><td>{{parent.name}}</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>


                                <!--  sub level repeats -->

                                <span ng-repeat="sub in parent.levels">{{sub}}sub</span>

                                <!--  end sub level repeat -->
                        </tr>
                    <!--  end parent levels -->
```

I know the span is nasty - I was just trying to get it working before styling. It doesn't seem to like this argument, the reasons of which I cannot figure out.

Also- in another section I am trying to just pull the information from the sub arrays (the form one), this I also cannot seem to get to work. I'm assuming its the same problem. So I'm doing

```
    <div class="subformWrappers" ng-repeat="level in levels track by $index">
```

And then inside that I'm trying to pull that data in the "forms" by doing this for example:

```
    <textarea rows="4" ng-model="level.form.options"></textarea>
```

Also to no success, I'm assuming both these problems are related to the same thing. Any input would be very helpful!! Thanks for reading.

Comment: i dont think span can work outside of td. can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of using nested repeats.  Hopefully this can get you going.

Json model

```
 $rootScope.list = [{
        "levels" : [{
                "targets" : [
                    "one",
                    "two",
                    "three",
                    "four"
                ],
                "response" : "response",
                "instructions" : "insturctions"
            }
        ],
        "name" : "Name One",
        "form" : [{
                "pfade" : "fade",
                "ptype" : " type",
                "psection" : "section",
                "lbehavior" : "l behave",
                "options" : "options",
                "tbehaviour" : "t behave"
            }
        ]
    },
    .
    .
    .
    ];
```

Some sample nested repeats, you can change to suit your needs.

```
  <div data-ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div>{{item.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="item.form[0].options"/></div>
    <ul data-ng-repeat="level in item.levels">
      <li data-ng-repeat="target in level.targets">{{target}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
  </div>
```

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/E2frec2QHBdOMksaZQj2